# An example of Forbidden subgraph problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, forbidden-subgraphs

The [forbidden subgraph problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_subgraph_problem) is one of the central problems in extremal graph theory. Given a forbidden subgraph $G$, the maximal number of edges in an $n$-vertex graph which does not have a subgraph isomorphic to $G$ is denoted as $ex(n,G)$. An equivalent problem is how many edges in an $n$-vertex graph guarantee that it has a subgraph isomorphic to $G$?

Now, I need to calculate $ex(4, P^3)$ and justify it with a proof. Is there an example of a graph on 4 vertices that is extremal in the set of all graphs without a $P^3$?

My idea so far: since $n=4,$ we would have ${ 4 \choose 2} =6$ edges. A copy of the complete bipartite graph  $K_{1,3}$  and/or a copy of  $C^3$ are the two types of graphs having the maximal of three edges which will not include $P^3.$ I am not sure about it let alone justify with a proof.

Comment: What is $P^3$ and what is $C^3$?

Comment: A path and a cycle with three vertices respectively

Comment: I thought those were usually denoted by $P_3$ and $C_3$. Anyway, the complete bipartite graph $K_{1,3}$ has a subgraph which is a path with $3$ vertices, and so does the graph you call $C^3$. A graph with no $P^3$ subgraph has no vertex of degree greater than $1$; if $n$ is even, the extremal $P^3$-free graphs on $n$ vertices are matchings.